# What is the "usual continuation argument"?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $u:[0,T]\to\mathcal{H}$ be the local solution of some initial value problem. Suppose we have proved that there exists a constant $C$ (that depends only on initial data) such that
$$\|u(t)\|_{\mathcal{H}}\leq C,\quad\forall \ t\in[0,T].$$
In this context, it's common to say something like "by the usual continuation argument, we conclude that our problem has a global solution".

Could someone explain me and give me some references about this result that is used to extend a local solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the same IVP with initial data at $t=T$ given by $u(T)$, with $\|u(T)\|\le C$. There will be a solution defined on $[T,2\,T]$ with $\|u(t)\|\le C$. Together with the solution on $[0,T]$, this defines a solution on $[0,2\,T]$. Iterate.

Comment: Could you explain me why we need the solution be bounded by $C$?

Comment: To make sure that the solution can be advanced each time the same $T$ units of time. Otherwise you advance the solution a positive but unknown quantity, extending the solution to a maximal interval that may be finite.